# Connect my live search(used select2) to my table in laravel 5.3

Tags: php, ajax, laravel

In here, im not using the data table. I tried to create separately, the live search and the table. The guide that I've used is in the select2 but their live search is not connected to table(I mean, when you tried to search in the data table the result will be display in the table).. So the problem is, how could i connect my live search to my table?

**My view**

```
@extends('layout.default')
@section('content')
<br><br>
<br><br>
<div class="container">
    <h4>Live Search using Laravel</h4>

    <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-6 pull-right" >

        <p class="pull-right">Click on the zip logo to download the file:<p>

            <a href="/live_search_laravel.zip" download="live-search(laravel).zip">
                <br><br>
                <img border="0" src="/images/ziplogo.png" class="pull-right" alt="AngularJS" width="50" height="42">

            </a>
        </div>



    </div>
    <br>
    <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-4 pull-right">
        <select class="js-example-basic-multiple" multiple="multiple">
            @foreach($data as $files)
            <option value="AL">{{ $files->original_filename }} </option>

            @endforeach
        </select>
    </div>
    <br><br>
    <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
        <div class="x_panel">

            <div class="x_content">
                <table class="table table-hover">

                    <tr>

                        <th>
                            Original File Name
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            Change File Name
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            File Extension
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            Image
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            Category
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            Status
                        </th>
                    </tr>
                    @foreach($data as $file)
                    <tr>

                        <th>{{ $file->original_filename}}</th> 
                        <th>{{ $file->rs_filename}}</th>
                        <th>{{ $file->file_extension}}</th>
                        <th><img src="/files/images/{{ $file->rs_filename }} "  width ="50px" height ="50px"></th>
                        <th>@if($file->category=="1"){{ "Laravel" }}@endif</th>
                        <th>
                            @if($file->status=="0")
                            <form action="/activateImage/{{  $file->id}}" method="post">
                                <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{{ csrf_token() }}}" />
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Activate</button>
                            </form>
                            @else
                            <form action="{{ url('deactivateImage', ['id' => $file->id]) }}" method="post">
                                <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{{ csrf_token() }}}" />
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Deactivate</button>
                            </form>
                            @endif
                        </th>

                    </tr>
                    @endforeach
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <h4>All Activated Images</h4>
    @foreach($data as $file)


    @if($file->status=="1")
    <div class ="row">
        <div class ="form-group">
            <img src="/files/images/{{ $file->rs_filename }} "  width ="50px" height ="50px">
        </div>
    </div>
    @endif
    @endforeach

    @stop
    @section('select2_js')
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/live_search_laravel/select2.js"></script>

    @stop
```

**JS**

```
$(".js-example-basic-multiple").select2({
    minimumInputLength: 3,
    placeholder: 'Search',
    minimumResultsForSearch: 20,


});
```

Answer (score 0):

The basic of select2 something like below:

```
$(".js-example-basic-multiple").select2({
    ajax: {
        url: "{{route('route-next')}}",
        dataType: 'json',
        type: "POST",
        data: function (term, page) {
          return {
                type: 'type_of_mine',
                q: term
            };
        },
        results: function (data, page) {
            return { results: data.results };
        }

    },
    initSelection: function (item, callback) {
        var id = item.val();
        var text = item.data('option');
        if(id > 0){
            var data = { id: id, text: text };
            callback(data);
        }
    },
    formatAjaxError:function(a,b,c){return"Not Found .."}
});
```

BTW, you start with basic of [select2](https://select2.github.io/announcements-4.0.html#removed-initselection)

Comment: Yes this link is for select2 website, try google with `select2`. Further, there is several number of help statement exist. Check it out with [laravel.io: Select2 dynamic select add](http://laravel.io/forum/04-22-2015-select2-dynamic-select-add)

Comment: Sir, im sorry but I really dont understand these codes.. What am I suppose to change?

Comment: When I tried your codes, I cant no longer search anything :( What am I suppose to do?

Comment: I can't able to teach you but you get this step by step help [here](https://www.sitepoint.com/community/t/how-to-bind-select2-and-mysql-databse-with-php/191658).

Comment: Any other suggestion?